# Implementing zendesk single signon

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, jwt, zendesk

I am implementing [Zendesk single signon](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_jwt_sso_examples/blob/master/c_sharp_handler.cs) functionality using [JSON Web Token](https://support.zendesk.com/entries/23675367-Setting-up-single-sign-on-with-JWT-JSON-Web-Token-) into my application. Based on the sample code, I am calling the ProcessRequest() function from my code-behind.

My code is:

```
JWTLogin jwtLogin = new JWTLogin();
jwtLogin.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["return_to"]);
```

however, I am getting an error

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'Zendesk.JWTLogin.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)' has some
>   invalid arguments

What is the "HttpContext" type parameter that I would pass when calling ProcessRequest() function?

Comment: You should check out ngDesk instead as its totally free and has awesome features. You can check it out here https://www.ngdesk.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Working With HttpContext.Current](http://odetocode.com/articles/112.aspx) your parameter should be `HttpContext.Current`

Answer (score 0):

The JWTLogin class is an IHttpHandler. It's not designed to be called directly.